# How to update the page after call Axios Successful ? React

Tags: reactjs

so I'm doing a project that uses `Axios` with `Json-server`, but I have a problem, every time I do a `Patch`, I have to give F5 on the homepage for it to update, I wanted know how I could do it so that it did not happen, and automatically.

My `Patch`:

```js
  onSubmitDate = event => {
    const newUrl = prompt("Please with new URL:");
    const personCurrent = event.target.value;
    axios.patch(`http://localhost:3004/employee/${personCurrent}`, {
    url_git: newUrl
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

My `Get`:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:3004/employee")
      .then(response => this.setState({ employee: response.data }));
  }
```

Someone would can help me?

Comment: can you use setInterval() or use package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-refetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the update is on the component you are handling.

For you to create a re-render of your component, you can simply set the state. [See more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)
What is the format of your response? Does it include the updated data you wish to display? If that is the case, it's easy, simply do a `setState` in your `then`:

```
  onSubmitDate = event => {
    const newUrl = prompt("Please with new URL:");
    const personCurrent = event.target.value;
    axios.patch(`http://localhost:3004/employee/${personCurrent}`, {
    url_git: newUrl
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({employee: response.data})
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

If the response is not providing the data you want updated in your component, your can simply do your GET of whatever data you want in the `then` of your PATCH and set the state on it's response. So something like this:

```
  onSubmitDate = event => {
    const newUrl = prompt("Please with new URL:");
    const personCurrent = event.target.value;
    axios.patch(`http://localhost:3004/employee/${personCurrent}`, {
    url_git: newUrl
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);        
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:3004/employee")
      .then(response => this.setState({ employee: response.data }));

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, i had that do same thing :(

Comment: A couple things: are you getting the response you are expecting? Are you using just a patch or the patch followed by the get?

Comment: The patch followed by the get, firt get, after i do the patch

Comment: Could you update your code on the OP? It will be easier to see and figure out what went wrong