# Update a Table with React Hooks when a Row is Added, Deleted and Modified? [Issue: Gets Before Post and Delete]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using Axios to get, put, and delete values from our database and have them displayed in a table; however, I need to refresh the page to see my changes. To find answers, I've visited these posts: [How to update the page after call Axios Successful ? React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145566/how-to-update-the-page-after-call-axios-successful-react), [refresh table after action in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024403/refresh-table-after-action-in-react), and [How can I use React Hooks to refresh a table when a row is deleted or added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647282/how-can-i-use-react-hooks-to-refresh-a-table-when-a-row-is-deleted-or-added)
Unfortunately, I am still stuck and unsure how to dynamically update table rows upon response updates.

**Update:** I have noticed that the `getValues` function runs prior to the post and delete methods, which is why it is currently showing the previous values before the methods execute.

**Axios.js** - Where I am using get and delete methods. They work as I've had responses printed on the console.

```
import axios from "axios";

const getValues = async () => {
  const values = await axios
    .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/")
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  return values;
};


const postValues = (values) => {
  axios
    .post("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Post Values: ", response.data);
      return response.data;
    });
};

const deleteValues = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  const deleteValues = axios
    .delete(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Delete Values: ", response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  return deleteValues;
};

export { getValues, postValues, deleteValues }
```

**ValuesTable.js** - Where the delete method executes

```
  import Axios from "./Axios";

  const [data, setData] = React.useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.getValues().then((result) => {
      setData(result.data);
    });
  }, [data]);

  return (
  {data.map((values) => {
    <TableRow/>
    <TableCell>{values.values}</TableCell>
    <TableCell>
      <Button
        onClick={() =>
           Axios.deleteValues(values.id);
        }
      />
    })};  
  )
```

**Form.js** - Where the post method executes

```
if (values.id === 0) {
  Axios.postValues(values);
} else {
  Axios.putValues(values, values.id);
}
```

UseState `setData(result.data)` loads all the existing values in the database.
Method `deleteValues` deletes a value in an array.
Method `postValues` adds a value into the database.

Comment: What does the `deleteValues` utility return? Is it your DB data with the specific element removed?

Comment: @DrewReese The `deleteValues` function deletes an object contained in an array. The console indicates that the delete function is working properly, so I expect the page to refresh with the updated values from the database. However, tt looks like this: `[{id: 0, name: "Jenny", age: 40}, {id: 1, name: "Lucy", age: 65}, {id: 2, name: "Ralph", age: 38}]`

Comment: That's not really what I asked. It returns `deleteValues` and I'm asking if that value is your `data` with the specific element removed. I think you need to return the response value you logged and then update state.

Comment: @DrewReese Ah. The response for the `deleteValues` function just indicates the specific object that was removed. Perhaps, the best way to resolve this is to call a getValues function again inside and after the 'deleteValutes' function initiates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't what to unconditionally call `setData` within an `useEffect` hook with `data` as a dependency as this will cause an infinite loop (render looping) to occur.

Since the `getValues` utility already unpacks the `response.data` value there is likely no need to do it again in your UI. Also, remove the `data` dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  Axios.getValues()
    .then((result) => {
      setData(result.results);
    });
}, []);
```

For the `deleteValues` utility, if `console.log("Delete Values: ", response);` is showing the correct values than I think you need to return this value from `deleteValues`.

```
const deleteValues = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  const deleteValues = axios
    .delete("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Delete Values: ", response);
      return response; // <-- new data values
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  return deleteValues;
};
```

Then in `ValuesTable` you need to update your `data` state with the new deleted values.

```
{data.map((values) => {
  ...
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        Axios.deleteValues(values.id)
          .then(data => setData(data));
      }}
    />
  ...
})};
```

#### Update

Ok, since the `deleteValues` utility ***doesn't*** return the updated `data` from the backend you will need to maintain your local state manually. I suggest doing this work in a callback handler. Upon successful deletion, update the local state.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState();

useEffect(() => {
  Axios.getValues().then((result) => {
    setData(result.data);
  });
}, []);

const deleteHandler = id => async () => {
  try {
    await Axios.deleteValues(id); // no error, assume success
    setData(data => data.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  } catch(err) {
    // whatever you want to do with error
  }
};

return (
  ...
  {data.map((values) => {
    <TableRow/>
    <TableCell>{values.values}</TableCell>
    <TableCell>
      <Button onClick={deleteHandler(values.id)}>
        Delete
      </Button>
    })}; 
  ...
)
```

Note that I've written `deleteHandler` to be a curried function so you don't need an anonymous callback function for the button's `onClick` handler. It encloses the current `id` in an "instance" of the callback.

#### Update 2

If you are making a lot of different changes to your data in the backend it may just be easier to use a "fetch" state trigger to just refetch ("get") your data after each backend update. Anytime you make a call to update data in your DB, upon success trigger the fetch/refetch via a `useEffect` hook.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState();
const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState(true);

const triggerDataFetch = () => setFetchData(t => !t);

useEffect(() => {
  Axios.getValues().then((result) => {
    setData(result.data);
  });
}, [fetchData]);

const deleteHandler = id => async () => {
  try {
    await Axios.deleteValues(id); // no error, assume success
    triggerDataFetch(); // <-- trigger refetch
  } catch(err) {
    // whatever you want to do with error
  }
};
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. I found an alternative solution (which I posted here) that may result in manually adding functions before all calls are made. If you have an efficient solution as oppose to what I have, please feel free to point out my bad practices. Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: @May Hmm, so it sounds like your DELETE endpoint isn't returning your new data. Yeah, just filtering by the `id` locally would also work, though, I would suggest using a functional state update since you are updating from an array, `setData(data => data.filter((item) => item.id !== values.id));`. This is to ensure you update from the previous state and not any stale/closed over state in the callback.

Comment: @May Ok, just saw your other comment above about the console log confirming what was deleted, not the new data. I updated my answer with an improvement upon your answer.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is definitely an improvement! However, I have concerns about the `postValues` and `putValues` since they may need additional functions to reflect changes on the front end. I have noticed that the `getValues` function runs prior to the `post` ,  `put`, and `delete` methods, which is why it is showing the previous values before the methods execute. What are your thoughts on the reason why `getValues` gets executed first? Is it due to `useEffect`? How can I executed `getValues` after every method is called?

Comment: @May That's why I moved the local state updates to be done *after* the asynchronous code successfully completed. If it's easier, you can use a "fetch" state trigger that you update any time you make a change in the backend. I'll add an example.

Comment: Oh. Thank you for your updates! I've learned so much from this experience, and now I have a very good idea on how I should approach the next step.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrong in here :

```
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.getValues().then((result) => {
      setData(result.data); // result has no data property
    });
  }, [data]);
```

Please try change to this

```
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.getValues().then((result) => {
      console.log("RESULT",result); // check the actually response from API
      setData(result.results); // the response of data is called results
    });
  }, [data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> import axios from "axios";  const getValues = async () => {  const values = await axios .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/")
> ```
>
> .then((response) => { return response.data; }) .catch(function (error)
> { console.log(error); });  return values;  };

I don't know why but what are you trying to achieve with this. You should either use async/await clause or then clause but you are using both atleast have some good practice of coding first.
Second I think you should use async await inside try catch and remove then/catch phrases to make your code more understandable, then if you store your result inside values then simply return `values.data` and your problem might be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `deleteValues` function deletes a specific object from the array on the server-side, I have decided to `filter` the list of objects in the array in order to remove the matching id to reflect on the front end. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

This is how I approached it.

```
{data.map((values) => {
  ...
    <Button
      onClick={() => {

        setData(data.filter((item) => item.id !== values.id)); // <- Filter

        Axios.deleteValues(values.id)
          .then(data => setData(data));
      }}
    />
  ...
})};
```